# For loop with two indices

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to use a for loop to get iterations like:
i=1,3,5,7,....,193
j=1,2,3,4,5,...,97

It can be also with only one index, but the same pattern as above. I tried the following:

```
for(i in seq(1,194,2)) {
matrix_kum[,i] <- sample_sum(matrix_kwh[,i], matrix_kwh[,i+1], n=10000, from=0)}
```

But then I end up having the values in every second column.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: try with `j <- (i+1)/2`

Comment: so simple, but so awesome. Thanks!